# Insert and remove nodes while preserving topological sort?

Tags: algorithm, insert, tree, time-complexity, topological-sort

I want to store a tree, where a node can have any number of children, as array. Each node has an associated value that gets calculated based on the parent value. Therefore, the array must be topologically sorted to ensure that the parent value is already calculated.

Since the tree is large and can be modified at runtime, I cannot resort the graph after every modification. Is there a way to insert into and remove from the tree while preserving the topological sort?

Comment: Is this really a [rooted tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rooted_tree#rooted_tree), where all the nodes eventually depend on a single root node, or is it a [directed acyclic graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) with multiple possible root nodes and dependents?

Comment: @dbc It's a tree, more precisely a scene graph. Each node has it's local transformation. In order to calculate it's global transformation, the node's local transformation must be multiplied with the parent's global transformation.

Comment: Since the topological order can be computed in linear time, what are you planning on doing with it in sublinear time?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Are you asking for my approach for cracking linear time or the reason why I want to? It's a real time game engine and there (shall) can be a lot of nodes in the scene.

Comment: How do you want to access the topological order?

Comment: Can you add the new node to have incoming edge from the last node of the sorted graph? That would preserve your current sorting order and the new will be appended in the end. Removal should be done from the end too.